# Couldn't restore postgres v11 from pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, database-restore, timescaledb

I'm making a backup from my postgresql database (v11) using `pg_basebackup` like this:

```sh
pg_basebackup -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -D /tmp/backup -Ft -z -Xs -P
```

The backup process is completed just fine without any errors.Then as a test I'd like to recover from the backup and for that I do the following steps:

1. Shutdown the postgres instance.
2. Delete everything from `/var/lib/postgresql/data` folder

   `rm -rf /var/lib/postgresl/data/*`
3. Untar the base archive there:

   `tar xvf /tmp/backup/base.tar.gz -C /var/lib/postgresql/data`
4. Untar the wal archives to a temporary directory

   `tar xvf /tmp/backup/pg_wal.tar.gz -C /tmp/archived_wals`
5. Create a file `recovery.conf` in the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` folder:

   ```
   touch /var/lib/postgresql/data/recovery.conf
   chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data/recovery.conf
   ```
6. Specify the recovery command in the recovery.conf file:

   `restore_command = 'cp /path/archived_wals/%f "%p" '`
7. Restart the postgres instance, and wait for the recovery to be finished.

However when postgres starts up I get the following error in the logs:

```sh
2020-02-04 11:34:52.599 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-02-04 11:34:52.599 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-02-04 11:34:52.613 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-02-04 11:34:52.709 UTC [18] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-04 08:39:54 UTC
cp: can't stat '/tmp/archived_wals/00000002.history': No such file or directory
2020-02-04 11:34:52.735 UTC [18] LOG:  starting archive recovery
2020-02-04 11:34:52.752 UTC [18] LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2020-02-04 11:34:52.752 UTC [18] FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
2020-02-04 11:34:52.752 UTC [18] HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/backup_label".
2020-02-04 11:34:52.753 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 18) exited with exit code 1
2020-02-04 11:34:52.753 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2020-02-04 11:34:52.769 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I guess I'm missing something, maybe I need to do additional configuration to postgres to be able to restore a `pg_basebackup` backup?

Comment: This should work.  At least, it works for me without the timescaledb.  You can copy the wal files from `/tmp/archived_wals/` directly into `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal` before you start it up, but that should not be necessary.

Comment: @jjanes Yes indeed. I had a type on the `recovery.conf` file. I had `"%p%` instead of `"%p"` and it screwed up things, however the error message was not really described the source of the problem really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it was my bad.

I enclosed the destination placeholder within **%** instead of double quotes in `recovery.conf`.

However the way I described for the backup and restore is valid and since I corrected the typo it works just fine for me, so I leave the question as it is for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The logging around this issue seems pretty unsatisfactory to me.  Your command "succeeded", but failed to create the file that it was expected to.  The part of the code that detects the problem is pretty far away from the part that caused the problem, and it doesn't know the details of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 /pgsql-11/bin/pg_basebackup -D /pgdata/pg11/data -X stream --waldir=/pglog/pg11/wal_log/ -P -c fast -h remoteserver\localserver -U username
```

Let me know if that works.